# Seeding data into postgresql issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, npm

I am trying to seed data into PostgreSQL with `npm run seed` though the seeding command ran successfully but when i checked the PostgreSQL database I couldn't find the data i seeded, please what could be wrong or what can I do to solve it

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific as the information here [NPM Seed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/seed) says; 'Seed comes with a Memory based storage engine.`. You will need to show what you are doing to get it into Postgres? **Add answer as update to question**.

Comment: okay i will try it thanks

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am not using `seed`  the seed file was written by a backend dev and I am trying to seed the model into Postgres database it created the tables successfully but it didn't insert any data, but sequelize was used, i don't just understand while the data is not being inserted into the database

Comment: 1) In  my original comment I specifically asked that the information be added to the question. 2) I am unable to reconcile 'I am trying to seed data into PostgreSQL with npm run seed ...' and ' I am not using seed ... I am trying to seed the model into Postgres database '.  Without a clear description of the steps you are taking there is really not much hope of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may check if there is a multiple instances of database is running on your machine - that happened to me a several times
So you may be seeding other instance

Comment: okay, lemme try it